# Varnish not respecting pass to backend for specified http hosts

Tags: docker, varnish

Running Varnish 6.0.6 in a Docker container for several Wordpress sites. I have several domains that I would like to pass to the backend verse having them cached, but the configuration is not behaving as intended. Looking to understand why I am unable to specify which sites I would like to pass. If I do something like:

```
    if ((req.http.host ~ "(domain.com) || (dev.domain.com)")) {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    } else {
        return (pass);
    }
```

then every hostname's content is cached where I would expect only the two specified domains to cache and everything not defined, to pass. Also, if I do not specify the directive, all sites are cached (as expected). If I use something like:

```
        if ((req.http.host ~ "(domain.com) || (dev.domain.com)")) {
                return (pass);
        }
```

then no sites are cached where I would expect everything to cache except for the two domains. What might be causing this behavior? I looked at the requests with `varnishlog`, the undefined domains are indeed being fetched from the backend verse being cached:

```
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_acl        NO_MATCH forbidden
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
```

Below is the entire Varnish configuration:

```
vcl 4.0;

# Set the default backend web server
backend default {
    .host = "app-proxy";
    .port = "8080";
    # Increase guru timeout
    # http://vincentfretin.ecreall.com/articles/varnish-guru-meditation-on-timeout
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
}

# Forbidden IP ACL
acl forbidden {
}

# Purge ACL
acl purge {
        "app-proxy";
        "192.168.0.0"/16;
    "127.0.0.1";
    "localhost";
        "172.16.0.0"/16;
        "10.0.0.0"/8;
}

# This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser)
sub vcl_recv {
    # Block the forbidden IP addresse
    if (client.ip ~ forbidden) {
            return (synth(403, "Forbidden"));
    }

        if ((req.http.host ~ "(domain.com) || (dev.domain.com)")) {
                return (pass);
        }

    # Compatibility with Apache format log
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Pss-Loop == "pagespeed_proxy") {
                set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
        }



    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Allow purging from ACL
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
        }                
        #return (purge);
                ban("req.http.host == " + req.http.host +
                      " && req.url == " + req.url);
                # Throw a synthetic page so the
                # request won't go to the backend.
                return(synth(200, "Purge added"));
    }

        if (req.method == "BAN") {
                # Same ACL check as above:
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        return(synth(403, "Not allowed."));
                }
                ban("req.http.host == " + req.http.host +
                      " && req.url == " + req.url);

                # Throw a synthetic page so the
                # request won't go to the backend.
                return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
        }


        # Only deal with "normal" types
        if (req.method != "GET" &&
                req.method != "HEAD" &&
                req.method != "PUT" &&
                req.method != "POST" &&
                req.method != "TRACE" &&
                req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
                req.method != "PATCH" &&
                req.method != "DELETE") {
            /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
            return (pipe);
        }

        # Only cache GET or HEAD requests. This makes sure the POST requests are always passed.
        if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
            return (pass);
        }

        # Configure grace period, in case the backend goes down
        #set req.grace = 15s;
        #if (std.healthy(req.backend)) {
        #    set req.grace = 30s;
        #} else {
        #     unset req.http.Cookie;
        #     set req.grace = 6h;
        #}

    # --- Wordpress specific configuration

    # Do not cache the RSS feed
    if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
        return (pass);
    }

        # Dont Cache WordPress post pages and edit pages
        if (req.url ~ "(wp-admin|post\.php|edit\.php|wp-login)") {
            return(pass);
        }
        if (req.url ~ "/wp-cron.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
            return (pass);
        }

        # Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages 
        if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|wc-api/*|addons|logout|lost-password)") { 
            return (pass); 
        } 

    # Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart 
        if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
            return (pass);
        }

        # Pass through the WooCommerce API
        if (req.url ~ "\?wc-api=" ) { 
            return (pass); 
        } 

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

        # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gid=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

        # Remove the Disqus cookie
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(disqus_unique)=[^;]*", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account|checkout|addons|wordpress-social-login|wp-login\.php|forumPM|members)")) {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }

        # Cache all static files by Removing all cookies for static files
        if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|pdf|png|rtf|swf|txt|woff|xml)(\?.*)?$") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
            return (hash);
        }

    # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

        # Ban outside access to wp-admin
        #if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" && !client.ip ~ purge) {
        #       error 403 "Forbidden";
        #}
        # Cache all others requests

    # --- End of Wordpress specific configuration

        # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
        # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html
        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
                # Do no compress compressed files...
                if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
                } else {
                        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                }
        }


        # Large static files should be piped, so they are delivered directly to the end-user without
        # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
        # TODO: once the Varnish Streaming branch merges with the master branch, use streaming here to avoid locking.
        if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|gz|wav|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
            return (pipe);
    }

    # Do not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        return (pass);
    }

        # Exclude caching Ajax requests
        if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
            return(pass);
        }

    # Cache all others requests
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
        # X-Forwarded-For set. If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
        # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
        # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
        # here. It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
        # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.

        set bereq.http.Connection = "Close";
        return (pipe);
}

# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);

    if (req.http.host) {
            hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
            hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
            hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    }

    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_hit {
    # Allow purges
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        #purge;
        return (synth(200, "Purged Hit"));
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    # Allow purges
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        #purge;
        return (synth(200, "Purged Miss"));
    }
    return (fetch);
}

# This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
sub vcl_backend_response {

        set beresp.ttl = 1800s;

    # Cache static files
        if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mp[34]|pdf|png|rar|rtf|swf|tar|tgz|txt|wav|woff|xml|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }

    return (deliver);
}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "uncached";
    }

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    # Remove Varnish version
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
        unset resp.http.Via;

        # Remove Google ModPageSpeed
        unset resp.http.X-Mod-Pagespeed;

    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was sending every request to the backend or specifying `return (pass)` which would prevent objects from being cached (basically sending them straight to the backend. A simple fix to not cache for the two domains is:

```
    if (req.http.host == "domain.com" || req.http.host == "dev.domain.com") {
        return (pass);
    }
```

The default backend was dropped for simplicity.